# How to use Gradle distribution plugin alongside with Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using Gradle application plugin:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.5.31"
    id("application")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("pl.gieted.flappy_bird.MainKt")
}
```

Unfortunately it is no longer working after I've moved to Kotlin multiplatform (the created distribution is empty).

I think the issue might be related to custom source sets, created by multiplatform plugin.

[image]

**How to set up application plugin to work with Kotlin multiplatform**?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Just as I've said in the question, the produced build is empty, just like if I had no sources.

Comment: what does the rest of your Gradle file look like?

Comment: I believe, I've added everything relevant in the question, yet here's a whole file: https://github.com/Gieted/flappy_bird/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the only thing required to make Kotlin multiplatform working with Java plugins is adding `withJava()` to the configuration:

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
}
```